# Display BIOS and grub on laptop monitor instead on TV plugged over HDMI

Tags: laptop, display, bios, hdmi

I have Asus k95vm laptop and it is connected to a tv over HDMI at all time. When I boot up the pc with the external monitor it seems to be primary because BIOS/POST and grub are shown on it, but not on laptop's display.

Is there a way that I can change this to display on laptops monitor, because the TV isn't always turned on, and I can't see BIOS settings and and can't select different OS to boot in grub unless my tv is turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.  Most BIOS will default to an external display, if one is connected.  The assumption is you have something preferable connected than the laptop LCD.

You can check your BIOS's settings for an option that is preferable.  Some BIOSs have an option to prefer built in over external.

Comment: Tnx. I guess i'll have to get used to this "feature". I don't have any settings in bios tied to this problem. Good thing is that i can switch displays with fn key combination and see when choosing items in grub, but it only works once, so every time i want to see these things on laptop display i have to press Fn + F8. Not a solution, but best i came up with. :/